# Selecting a named element in an Input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following Jquery:

```
<input type="text" value="hello" name="multy['helloworld']" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var hello = 'helloworld';
    alert($('input[name="multy['+hello+']"]').val());
  })
</script>
```

As you'll see it can't select the element by a named Array key. Is there a work around for this?

Ta.

Antony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remove the single quotes from the name of the element:

```
<input type="text" value="hello" name="multy[helloworld]" />
```

They are *absolutely* not required.

Comment: Super thanks. I don't have reputation but will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Although in my other code I just cannot get this to work: select[name="timeSlots['+name+']"]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do double escapes on the brackets when you send it to jquery so jquery will know to escape them, too.  Plus, please notice that I removed the single quote from the input in your example.

```
<input type="text" value="hello" name="multy[helloworld]" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('input[name=multy\\[helloworld\\]]').val());
</script>
```